Emscripten and Emulated System Calls
Emscripten compiles C and C++ to WASM, which is usually executed in a virtual machine in a browser. That makes me wonder.. how should system calls (or dependencies on kernel in general) work in this scenario? After all, the virtual machine knows no kernel at all.
An answer suggested it was not possible back in 2017. Seven more years have passed - has anything changed?

Interesting proposal, are you suggesting putting docker or an entire OS inside the browser to satisfy system calls?

I was just wondering what it does currently. There should be a list of syscalls that are not compiled correctly.

Here's some of the syscalls it supports by default, it is possible to add more through using the API. https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/src/library_syscall.js
